# SAS: can the COUNT() function be used for categorical variables?

Tags: count, sas

The categorical variable is "unique_carrier", which is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrxSK.png)

I want to count the number of each carrier in the variable "unique_carrier", My codes in SAS are as below,

```
PROC MEANS DATA=schedule_Jan NOPRINT; 
BY unique_carrier  _CHARACTER_ ;
OUTPUT OUT= flight_count COUNT(unique_carrier) =number_of_flights;
RUN;
```

but things go wrong when run this line (as below), and the log is, I wonder whether the COUNT function can be used for count categorical variable:

```
222  OUTPUT OUT= flight_count COUNT(unique_carrier) =number_of_flights;
                              -----
                              22
                              76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, (, /, CSS, CV, IDGROUP, IDGRP,
              KURTOSIS, LCLM, MAX, MAXID, MEAN, MEDIAN, MIN, MINID, MODE, N, NMISS, OUT, P1,
              P10, P20, P25, P30, P40, P5, P50, P60, P70, P75, P80, P90, P95, P99, PROBT, Q1,
              Q3, QRANGE, RANGE, SKEWNESS, STDDEV, STDERR, SUM, SUMWGT, T, UCLM, USS, VAR.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Comment: I don't think it can. But you can use the NLEVELS option in proc freq to get a count of the unique levels if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Otherwise the function you're looking for is N, but proc freq still seems like a better bet for this particular question.

Comment: The N statistic is the one that gives you the count of the number of observations. You probably what to use UNIQUE_CARRIER as a CLASS variable.  Also if you include all of the character variables in your BY statement, what is it that you are counting?

Comment: @Tom I think my question is not that clear. Actually, I want to count the variable  "unique_carrier" by group, as the unique_carrier are AA  AW AR B1 AA AA B1 B1   , I want the output like this : devided into two colums   AA   AW  AR  B1     3  1  1  3 , what should I do?

Comment: Edit the question to show what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count by using `PROC FREQ`.

```
proc freq data=schedule_Jan ;
  tables unique_carrier / noprint out=flight_count ;
run;
```

This will have the number of observations per value of UNIQUE_CARRIER in the variable COUNT.  You could add a dataset option to rename it to NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS if you want.

Or you can use `PROC MEANS` (aka PROC SUMMARY).

```
proc summary data=schedule_Jan nway;
  class unique_carrier;
  output out=flight_count ;
run;
```

This will have the number of observations in the variable _FREQ_.  You could use dataset option to rename this or add `N=number_of_flights` to the `OUTPUT` statement to add another variable with the same count.

Or you could even 'roll your own' by writing some SQL code.

```
proc sql ;
  create table flight_count as
    select unique_carrier
         , count(*) as number_of_flights
    from schedule_Jan
    group by 1
    order by 1
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom   , it really works!!! I am very appreciated !!You are really very nice and experienced !